Why the chatbot does not take the "system message" into consideration at all?
I am trying to apply a chatbot using the Azure OpenAI service with my own data. I want to give it specific instructions to personalize it. Since it utilizes ChatGPT, I can communicate with it in almost any language. Therefore, I have instructed it to respond to user queries in the language they were asked. Additionally, I have given it a name. However, it always responds in English to the first question (for subsequent questions it mostly changes), and when I ask for its name, it says it does not have one. This suggests that my "system message" is not being considered at all. I would be grateful for any help.

import os
import openai
import dotenv
import re

dotenv.load_dotenv()

endpoint = os.environ.get("AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT")
api_key = os.environ.get("AZURE_OAI_KEY")
deployment = os.environ.get("AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT")

client = openai.AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint=endpoint,
    api_key=api_key,
    api_version="2024-02-01",
)


# Initial system message
system_message = {
    "role": "system",
    "content": "Sei un assistente virtuale chiamato Jonathan. Rispondi sempre nella stessa lingua della domanda dell'utente.",
}

def get_response(user_query):
    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=deployment,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        messages=[
            system_message,
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": user_query,
            },
        ],
        extra_body={
            "data_sources": [
                {
                    "type": "azure_search",
                    "parameters": {
                        "endpoint": os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT"],
                        "index_name": os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX"],
                        "authentication": {
                            "type": "api_key",
                            "key": os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_KEY"],
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    )

    # Extract the response content
    response_content = completion.choices[0].message.content

    # Remove references like [doc4] using regex
    cleaned_response_content = re.sub(r'\[doc\d+\]', '', response_content)
    
    return cleaned_response_content

def main():
    while True:
        # Prompt the user for input
        user_query = input("Per favore inserisci la tua domanda (o 'esci' per terminare): ")

        if user_query.lower() in ['esci', 'exit', 'quit']:
            print("Bye bye!")
            break

        # Get and print the response
        response = get_response(user_query)
        print("Response: " + "\n" + response + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()




it says it does not have one. This suggests that my "system message" is not being considered at all.


It is due to OpenAI API issue because it handles system messages in different contexts or interactions.

Thanks @caos30, this approach allows to restrict the assistant's responses to only what is directly related to the provided context, avoiding unnecessary information about procedures and service features.

Check the language of the user input and instruct the chatbot to respond in that language. Use a language detection library like pip install langdetect .

Code:
import os
import openai
import dotenv
import re

dotenv.load_dotenv()

endpoint = os.environ.get("AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT")
api_key = os.environ.get("AZURE_OAI_KEY")
deployment = os.environ.get("AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT")

client = openai.AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint=endpoint,
    api_key=api_key,
    api_version="2024-02-01",
)

# Simplified initial system message
system_message = {
    "role": "system",
    "content": "Sei un assistente virtuale chiamato Jonathan. Rispondi sempre nella stessa lingua della domanda dell'utente.",
}

def get_response(user_query):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=deployment,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        messages=[
            system_message,
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": user_query,
            },
        ]
    )

    # Print the full API response for debugging
    print("Full API Response:", response)

    # Extract the response content
    response_content = response.choices[0].message.content

    # Remove references like [doc4] using regex
    cleaned_response_content = re.sub(r'\[doc\d+\]', '', response_content)
    
    return cleaned_response_content

def main():
    while True:
        user_query = input("Per favore inserisci la tua domanda (o 'esci' per terminare): ")

        if user_query.lower() in ['esci', 'exit', 'quit']:
            print("Bye bye!")
            break

        response = get_response(user_query)
        print("Response: " + "\n" + response + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Request body:
{
    "model": "{{AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT}}",
    "temperature": 0.5,
    "max_tokens": 1000,
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a virtual assistant named Jonathan. Always respond in the same language as the user's question."
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "What is your name?"
        }
    ]
}

Result:

Output:
{
    "choices": [
        {
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "I am a virtual assistant named Jonathan. How can I assist you today?"
            }
        }
    ],
    "id": "chatcmpl-...",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "created": 1621968672,
    "model": "gpt-4",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 20,
        "completion_tokens": 10,
        "total_tokens": 30
    }
}


It is working in this case because you have removed Azure AI Search and it answers questions with general information. What I need is to use my own Knowledge Base to answer questions.
